# SQLite (like) query returning all results when queried with special characters

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a question regarding android SQLite: I have a group of records in a table. I am querying the records using some special characters like {" , [ , ], *, &, ^, %, $, #}" . It returning the correct results in a cursor.

When I am using a special character {  '  } (single quote), it displaying all results where no results with that character in my database. I executed the same query in SQLita tool it is working perfect, but in my program it is returning all the results. Why this is happening ? How to resolve this issue. please help me in resolving this issue.

The code is here:

```
if( search_tag!=null && search_tag.length() > 0 )
        {
            query_filtered.append("("+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DOCS.COL_TITLE+" like "+"'%"+search_tag+"%')");
        }
```

The query is here:

```
select 
    id as _id, category_array, title, 
    building_name, content_type_array, url, type_of_level 
from 
    documents_list 
where 
    (title like '%'%')
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL strings, quotes must be escaped by doubling them:

```
... WHERE title LIKE '%''%'
```

To avoid formatting problems like this, you should use parameters instead:

```java
String title = "'";
db.query(..., "title LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + title + "%" }, ...);
```

Comment: First of all CL provided you with the necessary hint to use a double tick. Thus you should mark this as the correct answer. I also think that you didn't apply his answer correctly, because what he describes is the correct way to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This query is working fine for me

```
String select = "Select time from english_details where title = '"
                + title + "'";
```

So you can try like this

```
String select = "Select time from english_details where title = '%"
                + title + "%'";
```

Comment: Not working for me. select id as _id,category_array,title,building_name,content_type_array,url,type_of_level from documents_list where (title = '%"'"%'") returns no results. But select id as _id,category_array,title,building_name,content_type_array,url,type_of_level from documents_list where (title = '%"building"%'") also returning no results even it has the results.